# Nodejs - Is there any module existing similar to request module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, restify

I want to make rest api calls from node server. I have currently request module in my mind.
 Would you suggest any other best module for REST calls(get/post) for production practise in nodejs ??

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Do you have any specific requirements?

Comment: Yes.. I want to consume webservices to get the response for my app. I use Express server on node platform. So i have to make rest calls binding the data in header/body to consume the web services hosted on different server and get the response back. I need an alternative for Request module.

Answer (score 0):

[Restify](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify) was designed specifically for serving RESTful APIs (instead of serving web pages). And it can call RESTful APIs as well.

Comment: I personally use backbone directly on server for server 2 server comm via restful APIs. works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) to create Rest API. Very easy to use!

> Sails.js automatically generates a RESTful JSON API for your app. That means you don't have to write any backend code to build simple database apps.

**Install:**

```
sudo npm -g install sails
```

**Create app:**

```
sails new testProject
```

**Lift server:**

```
cd testProject
sails lift
```

And you are ready!

**Update**

Regarding your comment, you don't want to *create* a REST API, but rather consume an existing one.

I found this [node module](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client) called Node-rest-client. I haven't tried it myself, but looks like this could be what you are looking for.

> Allows connecting to any API REST and get results as js Object.

Comment: Sails seems like a framework. What i need is just a module to consume webservices running on Other server.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://deployd.com/) is a nodeJS module called "Deployd" that will help you in creating REST APIs (get/post) in seconds, its community is very limited though. Its quite powerfull as well.

Simply install deployd, it expects nodeJS and mongoDB to be installed already. Deployd provides PHPMyAdmin like web interface through which you can create your APIs and for fine tuning work on deployd's Event API which gives you control on behavior of individual events like GET/POST/DELETE/PUT/VALIDATE etc